# WebRTC PaaS which supports both MCU / SFU and Android / iOS

Tags: webrtc, skylink

I'm looking for a WebRTC / media server hosting service which supports:

- SFU or MCU server
- Android / iOS SDK (EDIT: Android is not mandatory)

I need both above because I have to implement an audio only (no video needed) conference app which can involve 20 participants in one conference session.

I'm contacting to Skylink https://skylink.io/ but I wonder if there are any alternatives.

Do you know any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have quite a few of them. 20 participants in am audio call is not that many. SFU/MCU is also not a big deal, the only concern is wether you need people to call in / call out.

Here is a short list. You might want to chaco location and existing clients. skylink.io might not be the most recommended option.

- sinch
- sightcall
- apidaze
- apizee
- plivo
- ooVoo
- forge / xura
- voximplant
- respoke
- tokbox
- tropo
- [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video)
- ...

Comment: Wow, do they all have SFU / MCU servers, and mobile SDKs are capable of using SFU / MCU?

Comment: SFU/MCU servers are NOT visible directly from the API. It is just a component of the platform to allow for more people in a call. You should not focus on MCU/SFU availability, but on the availability of the features you need for your call (here 20 people in a call is what you want, HOW they achieve that is not so important). In any case, most of them DO have a media server (whether SFU or MCU). Almost all of them have mobile SDK as well.

Comment: Agreed. I'd like to ask you one more thing: I would need people to call in / call out to a conversation, but I'm not sure why this would be a concern. do those services have any difference in this point?

Comment: the technical answer is that this is a concern, as you MUST have an MCU somewhere in the media path to mix the audio for the people using real phones as real phones only support one audio stream at a time. You also need a SIP gateway as the usual path to go from webrtc to phones is WEBRTC => SIP => IP-PBX => PSTN termination (phone line). 
The practical answer is, .. you don't care how they do it :-) Most of the vendors/products I listed except tokbox have it. You will have to check them one by one, i don't maintain a feature list. Be careful about which countries phone numbers they support.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/).
They have SFU based video and audio chat solution.

ConnectyCube has both Android and iOS SDKs. They also have JS SDK if you might need Web app later too.

The solution allows implementing both audio and video, but if you do not need video, you can use audio only and it should increase the capacity compared to video option.